# Which kind of software architecture pattern is used for quantum software design?

Tags: qiskit

I'm interested in developing quantum software and am curious about the architectural patterns commonly employed in this domain. In classical software design, we have patterns like publisher-subscriber, layered architecture, etc. For quantum software development, are there analogous patterns that are commonly used? For example, are there established patterns related to qubit gate management, measurement, or other quantum-specific operations? I would appreciate insights or references to guide me in structuring quantum software effectively.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.